# Load date to input field after selecting from Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

What I am trying to do is, after selecting a date on [**Bootstrap Datetimepicker**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), it should load a value on my input field, but I don't know how to do that. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/ekm0on2a/15/).

This is my jQuery for datetimepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('.datetimepickerinline').datetimepicker({inline: true});
});
```

I need to use it for all inputs, or in other words, closest input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution you want: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/ekm0on2a/12/)

```
$('.datetimepickerinline').on('change dp.change', function(e){
    $('input').val($(this).data('date'));
});
```

See reference [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/)

Further more, I noticed that you want use `moment.js`

You can use something like this, using custom format:

```
$('.datetimepickerinline').on('change dp.change', function(e){
   $('input').val(moment($(this).data('date')).format('DD/MM/YYYY, h:mm'));
});
```

Comment: If I have multiple inputs then it adds to all inputs value. How to change that?

Comment: Here is solution :https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/ekm0on2a/18/ .You need set an id to desired input.

Answer (score 2):

You called so many unwanted libraries. Just try this bootstrap datepicker. Hope this work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true,
    forceParse: false,
  });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/20/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply class 'datetimepickerinline' on your input field.

```
<input id="" placeholder="press to show calendar" class="input datetimepickerinline">
```

Try this fiddle : - https://jsfiddle.net/ekm0on2a/11/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add datepicker class in your input field.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<div class="my-example">
  <input id="datepicker" placeholder="press to show calendar" class="input input-datepicker">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="datetimepickerinline">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

//script

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({inline: true});
});
```